# Creating a label from another label in Perforce

Tags: perforce

I'm trying to create an updated version of a label. As in, go from my_label-1.4.0 to my_label-1.4.1. To do this, I selected the 1.4.0 and chose Create Label from 'my_label-1.4.0'

Here's the problem, though: The previous label has a little over a thousand files. But creating a new label from the old one does not appear to copy over the labeled files as well, just the general workspace. Is there any way to copy over the included files from one label to another that doesn't involved manually selecting them one at a time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

p4 label creates the label specification but does not label/tag files with the label.  p4 labelsync is used to label/tag files at a specific version with the already created label specification.

However, p4 tag will both create the label specification and label/tag files with that label on one command.  So, you could use p4 tag to create the new label spec and then tag the files from the other label:

p4 tag -n -l my_label-1.4.1 //...@my_label-1.4.0

which will first create the label specification my_label-1.4.1 and then tag/label the files from the other label via the file specification "//...@my_label-1.4.0".  Note: the -n is a preview, remove it to actually do the command after previewing that what it will do is what you want.

Comment: Outstanding, friend, that is exactly what I'm looking for. Can't seem to find a matching command in P4V, but this should do for the time being.

Comment: This does the trick. However the Views in original Label is not copied to the new Label. How to do that?

Answer (score 4):

You can also perform this operation from within P4V. 
Process is similar to Applying a Label, 
but at the bottom of the Label Files, Type the desired Label.

1. Right click on a folder and Select 'Label...'
2. Enter the new Label in the Label field.
3. Select Radio button "Specify Revision using:"
4. Select Label from the dropdown and Enter the old Label.
5. Click Label button